# How to determine size in lines of console pane in PowerShell ISE?

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

In the PowerShell console, I can determine the number of lines displayed in the screen by using either of the following:

```
[console]::WindowHeight
$host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Height
```

Both of these are $null in PowerShell v4.0 ISE. I can find the toal numbers of lines in the console pane buffer with this:

```
$psISE.CurrentPowerShellTab.ConsolePane.LineCount
```

However, I haven't been able to find an equivalent to $host.UI.RawUI.WindowSize.Height. Is there another way to find this?

Comment: The UI doesn't really have a height, since it's a Forms window. The viewport has a size, but it is not tied to the number of lines visible.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

(Converting my comment to an answer)

The UI doesn't really have a height, since it's a Forms window. The viewport has a size, but it is not tied to the number of lines visible.